# How can I transport sunlight (with UV, IR etc...) across space?

Tags: optics, energy-efficiency, solar-energy, fiber-optics, spectrometry

I currently have a tiny vertical farm which I am trying to make as energy efficient as possible.
A big chunk of my power consumption comes from LED lights which are powered by solar panels/batteries, and I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to directly carry sunlight (including the invisible spectrum part (IR/UV) which are very important for plants), perhaps using a system of mirrors and prisms? The question may seem naive, I am a beginner in optics and energy, but the energy losses between the external light and that of the LEDs seems colossal.

Comment: Have you checked out solar tubes?

Comment: UV is tough. Most things absorb considerable UV, and those that are considered transparent to UV are real expensive and tend not to be manufacturable in many different forms. On top of the losses in a very thick medium like fiber optic line since transmission is never 100% efficient.